# I like to get a specific property of an element from the application modeller of Blueprism like Web Value, Web Style etc. How is this possible?

Tags: process, automation, blueprism, rpa

Yes, I know: when using read stage it is possible to get some properties like the web path, web text, URL etc. But there are not ALL properties available. Nevertheless, when capturing an element via Application Modeller there are some other useful properties like web value, web style. How can I save them into a data item? Via JavaScript this is not possible

Comment: Seeing as though you're referencing properties akin to "Web Path" and "Web Text", is it safe to assume you're working with Chrome/Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible via JavaScript, it's just not "one action" simple. That being said, it's not much more difficult - it's "two actions" simple. You need to execute a javascript that will write your value into some element that BP can read from and *then* use the Reader stage to read that value from it.

You can have a look at similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610246/get-data-from-web-page-using-javascript-in-blueprism/).

Comment: when I set a value in some element that BP can read from, then nevertheless I am not able to read from the element I actually like to read from.

Comment: Let me rephrase it: Use javascript to set value of an element you can read from with a value that you are interested. I just tried and it works.